# ChunkLoadError in Angular ThreeJS app only on Safari

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, ecmascript-6, three.js

I'm using ThreeJS in Angular. Last week I compiled my code and upload the latest  version of app to server then I faced the errors below on Mac and iPhone.

```
SyntaxError: Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference

Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 4 failed. (missing: https://www.visetra.com/4.7c25f3405f531545d2e4.js)
```

[image]

These errors are exist **only on Safari**. However the missing chunk file according to Safari is accessible. Empty cache or cleaning cache in other ways did not help.

I had research about the errors and the situation. I found 2 ways which are creating global error handler for chunk load error and transforming app to PWA to solve the problem with service worker. I tried handle the ChunkLoadError and reloading when the error happens. However it is not fixed and infinite reloading happened. Also I tried transforming my application to PWA and the result was same.

Generally all the approach about to determine the reason of this problem are saying that in every compilation with --output-hashing=chunk (this option is default of angular compiler) file names are being changed and naturally browsers cant find the correct files. Therefore in most of solution, it is suggested to not removing old files. But according to these solutions cache cleaning is supposed to fix the problem. However it is not worked for me.

While I was trying things, I have realized that ***if I remove components that include ThreeJS then these errors are gone.*** Maybe you can think it is about to change ES5 to ES6 because of the package but I was using ES6 since at the beginning.

The dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~11.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "three": "^0.126.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  }
```

Comment: I'm having the same problems.

For me it worked by downgrading to `0.125.2`

Something seems to have broken in > 0.126

Comment: @LeonRadley Thank you! It works for me too. I am going to write this issue to three github page. If you write your answer below, I can mark as right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what changed exactly, but with Angular version `12.2.0` and three.js version `0.131.3` this problem seems to have been fixed!

<s>I'm having the same problem as of Angular version `12.0.2` and three.js version `0.129.0`. It has something to do with ES6.</s>

For me the only two possible solutions right now are:

- downgrading three.js to version `0.125.2` (as Leon suggested above)

or

- downgrading the target in `tsconfig.json` to `es5`

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es5"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Downgrading three.js to version 0.125.2 worked for me also as @Leon Radley suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Having exactly the same issue.

Ive tried many thinngs:

1. Downgrade/Upgrade ThreeJs
2. Add typings
3. Change the import from importing the node_modules to importing just the minified file.
4. Move the lib from node_modules to assets.
5. Tried to conditionally load the Angular Module that uses the lib (disabling load for safari).

Nothing helped so far.